# Why is my AngularJS directive caching previous values?

Tags: angularjs, navbar, angular-directive

I have implemented "navbar" in my web application using AngularJS directive. When the user is logged in, it displays the username of the logged in user. But, when I log in as a different user, it still displays the username of the previous user until I manually refresh the window.
Is there any solution to this?

This is the navigation-directive.html

```
<header class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ABC app</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button> 
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul ng-if="vm.isLoggedIn()" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/homeuser">Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/myappointments">My Appointments</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link">Welcome!<strong> {{vm.loggedInUser}} </strong><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" ng-click="vm.logout()">Logout</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Below is the navigation-directive.js

```
angular.module('bbms').directive('mhNavigation', mhNavigation);

function mhNavigation(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'angular-app/navigation-directive/navigation-directive.html'
  };
}
```

And in my HomeController I am doing

```
vm.loggedInUser = response.data.username;
```

I have copied the relevant part from my home controller

Comment: Where is your code? Add your code in question whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: Provide code and check `binding` of directive. Directive is not aware of change in the value of `username`

Comment: directive and controller has different scope, `$scope. username` of your controller and `$scope. username` of your directive are different variables. update your controller variable when directive's variable changed.